# Android Wheel-like loading icon

Tags: android

I'm trying to render a loading circle in one activity whose data gets populated by an async task. I'm not using default progressbar, because the icon in older version of Android looks like this:

[image]

I know how to use an ImageView or ProgressBar with a custom image and a rotation animation, but I haven't been able to find new official Android's looking icon anywhere. The one that looks like this:

[image]

Or maybe there is another way to generate this kind of spinning wheel animation in Android 2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check folder SDK_DIR\platforms\android-x\data\res\drawable-hdpi.
There should be spinner drawables like "spinner... "

Comment: Thanks, I had googled a lot and couldn't find a pointer anywhere.

Comment: but that's without animation. how do you animate that one?

Answer (score 7):

In general it's good to stick with the style set on that system.

If you still want the newer spinning wheel animation, set the `indeterminateDrawable` XML property on the ProgressBar. You can find the drawable XML files in the SDK folder under `[android-sdk]\platforms\android-17\data\res\drawable` called `progress_medium.xml` and others. You'll also need the referenced icon files stored in the `drawable-****` folders.

Comment: but that's without animation. how do you animate that one?

Comment: Check this out: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html